# Print formatted list

Tags: python, string, list, formatting

I have a list:

```
l = [i for i in range(9)]
```

and I need to format its string representation as follows:

```
'{0}{1}{2}\n{3}{4}{5}\n{6}{7}{8}'.format(l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3], l[4], l[5], l[6], l[7], l[8])
```

Is there a more elegant/brief way to do such a thing?

I thought of something like the following:

```
'{0}{1}{2}\n{3}{4}{5}\n{6}{7}{8}'.format([l[i] for i in range(9)])
```

But it seems it doesn't work.
Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do argument unpacking:

```
'{0}{1}{2}\n{3}{4}{5}\n{6}{7}{8}'.format(*l)
```

Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for more details.

Comment: or just `(('{}'*3+'\n')*3).format(*l)` for Python > 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, Here's a Python 2 style version:

```
L = list('abcdefghi')
print '\n'.join([''.join(u) for u in zip(*[L[i::3] for i in (0, 1, 2)])])
```